# Revert excluded files from .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the following folder structure:

```
a/b/c/
a/b/d/s/g/foo.js
a/b/e/t/h/i/foo.js
a/b/f/u/j/foo.js
```

and I am trying to ignore the folder `a/b` but exclude the file `foo.js`

In `.gitignore` I have tried

```
a/b/*
!a/b/**/foo.js
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `a/b/*` matches the directories `a/b/c`, `a/b/d`, etc., so un-ignoring files inside those already-ignored directories doesn’t help.

I think you can start by ignoring all paths, then un-ignoring all directories (the trailing slash – Git doesn’t track empty directories), to be able to finally un-ignore the specific files you want:

```
a/b/**/*
!a/b/**/*/
!a/b/**/foo.js
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check your Git version using:

```
git --version
```

to see which option is best for you.

According to the gitignore documentation for versions lower than 2.41 and higher than 2.34, a structure similar to the following should work:

```
a/*
!a/b.py
```

Therefore, a structure like the following should work:

```
a/b/**
!a/b/**/
!a/b/**/foo.js
```

Make sure to place this structure in your .gitignore file, located at the root of your Git repository.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. This answer is 4 characters less the the other one :-)

Comment: What changed in Git 2.34?